# How to use VSTest results and other .NET plugins in Jenkins Pipeline (old workflow)?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

Due to some company changes, we're forced to switch to Jenkins as CI tool. And while this doesn't seem like a bad idea after all, we're having a lot of headaches due to lack of support for non-Java application, especially for the Pipeline (old Workflow) plugin and of course our lack of Jenkins knowledge (which is kind of none at this point).

```
node('master') 
{
    try 
    {
        stage('Checkout, restore, build') 
        {
            //Checkout the code from the repository
            git branch: '<branch_name>', credentialsId: '<credentials_ID>', url: '<repo_URL>'    

            //git clean
            bat returnStatus: true, script: 'git clean -fdx'

            //Perform dotnet restore and nuget restore
            bat returnStatus: true, script: '''for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (\'dir project.json /b /s\') do dotnet restore "%%a"
            "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.jenkins\\workspace\\nuget.exe" restore "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.jenkins\\workspace\\CI\\<solution_name>.sln"'''

            //Build the solution
            bat returnStatus: true, script: '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MSBuild\\14.0\\Bin\\msbuild.exe" /p:DebugType=full /p:platform=x64 /p:configuration=release /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 '
        }
    } catch(err)
    {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    }

    jobDsl("${env.JOB_NAME}") {
        steps {
            bat returnStatus: true, script: '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TestWindow\\vstest.console.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.jenkins\\workspace\\CI\\<path_to_tests_dll>"  /TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=UnitTest|TestCategory=ContinuousTest" /EnableCodeCoverage /Platform:x64 /logger:trx'
        }
        publishers {
            archiveXUnit {
                msTest {
                    pattern('"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.jenkins\\workspace\\CI\\TestResults"')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting errors for the `jobDsl`:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected named arguments but got
>   [CI, org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2@1a706730]     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.parseArgs(DSL.java:442)    at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeDescribable(DSL.java:251)
>     at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:129)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
>     at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:103)
>     at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
>     at
>   org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
>     at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:1)     at
>   ***cps.transform***(Native Method)    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor295.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
>     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ClosureBlock.eval(ClosureBlock.java:46)
>     at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:74)     at
>   com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:165)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:328)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:80)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:240)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:228)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
>     at
>   jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

This really makes me think that it's not the good approach, so can someone shed a bit of light and guide me on the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not mix [Pipeline DSL](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) and [Job DSL](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/). Those are completely different things.

The [XUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) has built-in support for Pipeline DSL since version 1.100, see [JENKINS-27240](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27240) for details. So you do not need to try to embed a Job DSL script in your Pipeline script.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do so using the "**MSTestPublisher**" class,

So the final pipeline is:

```html
node {
stage 'Checkout'
    checkout scm

stage 'Build'
    bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" restore \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\""
    bat "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" build \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\""

stage 'UnitTests'
    bat returnStatus: true, script: "\"C:/Program Files/dotnet/dotnet.exe\" test \"${workspace}/MyProg.sln\" --logger \"trx;LogFileName=unit_tests.xml\" --no-build"
    step([$class: 'MSTestPublisher', testResultsFile:"**/unit_tests.xml", failOnError: true, keepLongStdio: true])
}
```

I have uploaded some examples that I made to my GitHub for everyone to use and contribute, feel free to take a look:

https://github.com/avrum/JenkinsFileFor.NETCore

Those pipline jenkinsfile will add this pipline template to your build:

[image: Example Jenkins Pipeline|Solid]